# use variable in FROM statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I am trying to create a query that will be executed once for a specific table in a specific database in each server in `sys.server`.

For each `server.database.dbo.table` I want to know the contents.

So what I need is something like:

```
declare @numrows int = (select count(*) from sys.servers)
declare @i int = 1

while @i <= @numrows
BEGIN
declare @servername varchar(max) = (select servernaam from #servers where rij = @i)

select * from @servername.DATABASE.DBO.TABLE

set @i = @i+1

END
```

However, the `@servername` in `@servername.DATABASE.DBO.TABLE` does not seem to work.

Suggestions? Thanks for thinking with me.

Comment: You might be interested in [How to: Execute Statements Against Multiple Servers Simultaneously](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964743(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use dynamic sql:

```
declare @numrows int = (select count(*) from sys.servers)
declare @i int = 1
declare @Sql(1000)
declare @servername varchar(max)

while @i <= @numrows
BEGIN
select @servername = servernaam 
from #servers where rij = @i

set @Sql = 'select * from '+@servername+'.DATABASE.DBO.TABLE'
exec(@Sql)

set @i = @i+1

END
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms188332%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) is more informations about exec.

Comment: You cannot use `SP_EXECUTESQL` in this way, you still have to use string concatenation to make the query in the same way as you did for `EXEC()`, although I'd still advocate using `SP_EXECUTESQL`. I would also advise using `'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@Servername) + '.DATABASE.SCHEMA.TABLE'` to allow for any server names with reserved characters in, or Server names that are reserved words.

Comment: @`GarethD` `t-clausen.dk`  You have right! Thanks! I edited the. post

Comment: @t-clausen.dk - what's wrong with `declare` inside a loop? `declare`s don't participate in control flow at all.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Maybe it's work correctly It's not good practice.

Comment: @Parado: could you elaborate on that?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeleiever - I assumed it would give the error,  The variable name <variable> has already been declared. After your post i tested and realized i was wrong.

Comment: I now declared it outside the loop and set it inside the loop, it makes it a bit more readable.

Comment: @Henrov It's good practice because it's more readable and faster to understand code. Example as above is short, but procedures with more than 500 lines to understand, it will complicated. I prefer keep declaration, validation and logic in different blocks. If we mix them, code will be not readable.

Comment: I thought initially it would be more readable like this; declare when you need it...