# Create table with instruction into @parameter in stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to create a table from this code in SQL Server, but the stored procedure returns an error

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Recovery_CountryCode (@NombreTabla SYSNAME)
AS
DECLARE @ParamDefinition nvarchar(500);
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar (4000);
 SET @SQLString=N'SELECT Name
                INTO @TableName
                FROM AdventureWorks2008R2.Production.Location';
SET @ParamDefinition=N'@TableName SYSNAME';
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParamDefinition, @TableName=@NombreTabla;
GO
```

I want avoid define table

When I call the stored procedure:

```
EXEC Recovery_CountryCode @NombreTabla='Paises';
```

I get the follow message:

> *Mens. 102, Nivel 15, Estado 1, Línea 2
>   Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de '@TableName'.*

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12508973/use-variable-in-from-statement/12509011#12509011) is similar problem and solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can just concatenate the SQL inside your procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Recovery_CountryCode (@NombreTabla SYSNAME)
AS
DECLARE @ParamDefinition nvarchar(500);
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar (4000);
 SET @SQLString=N'SELECT Name INTO ' + 
                @NombreTabla + 
                ' FROM AdventureWorks2008R2.Production.Location';
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't bind variables to table names in this way. You need to do something like

```
Declare @sql nvarchar(max), @NombreTable sysname = 'Test'

Set @sql = N'Select Name Into ' + @NombreTable +
           N' From AdventureWorks2008R2.Production.Location

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html is recommended reading.